# Renaming a file name after uploading it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I want to upload an mp3 file using paperclip and i want to add an extention on the file after uploading, like the name of the song is "just dance.mp3" and i want to rename it to "just dance.mp3(www.hypejamz.com)" i have this bit of code in my song model

```
after_create :normalize_song

  Paperclip.interpolates :normalized_mp3_file_name do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.normalized_mp3_file_name
  end

  def normalized_mp3_file_name
    "#{self.mp3_file_name.gsub( /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]/, ' ')}#{'(www.hypejamz.com)'}"
  end

  def normalize_song
    self.update_attributes(:mp3_file_name => normalized_mp3_file_name, :name => "#{self.title} by #{self.user.name}")
  end
```

if i do it this way, the file output is "just dance.mp3 (www.hypejamz.com)(www.hypejamz.com)"
 but i want the output to be "just dance.mp3(www.hypejamz.com)". thank you

Comment: are you telling that the file is stored with  "just dance.mp3 (www.hypejamz.com)(www.hypejamz.com)" file name ?

Comment: @PriteshJ yes it is stored that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you need, This is a a small hackish way you can do it.

```
before_save :change_mp3_file_name

def change_mp3_file_name
    if !self.mp3_file_name.nil?
      self.mp3.instance_write(:file_name, "#{self.mp3_file_name}(www.hypejamz.com)")
    end
end
```

This will save the file name with "(www.hypejamz.com)" appended to file itself and will be retrieved as same.

Answer (score 2):

Here are both a spec that covers the string modification you're asking about, as well as some code that makes it pass.

```
require 'rspec'

class SongUpload
  attr_accessor :file_name

  def initialize(file_name)
    @file_name = file_name
  end

  def normalized_mp3_file_name
    @file_name + "(www.hypejamz.com)"
  end
end


describe SongUpload do
  before(:each) do
    @upload = SongUpload.new("just dance.mp3")
  end

  context "#normalized_mp3_file_name" do
    it "should append the string (www.hypejamz.com) to the file_name" do
      @upload.normalized_mp3_file_name.should eq "just dance.mp3(www.hypejamz.com)"
    end
  end  
end
```

I'm almost positive this isn't what you're looking for, but it provides a foundation.

Answer (score 1):

As per what I understand is as you are using interpolations it appends (www.hypejamz.com) to the path or url of the file when you retrive to the filename in the database.

As you are updating the filename with "(www.hypejamz.com)" appended to the filename in the database, while retrieving the file with url or path methods of paperclip while interpolating "(www.hypejamz.com)" get appended to the filename once again.

suggestion will be not to update the file_name in update_attributes

```
  def normalize_song
    self.update_attributes(:name => "#{self.title} by #{self.user.name}")
  end
```

Comment: what i am talking about is that i want to add the (www.hypejamz.com) to the mp3 file saved on the filesystem itself